# Smooth animation of second hand

Tags: animation, qml

I am building a simple animated clock with QML and it works, but I want to have a "sweep second" in which the second hand rotates continuously and smoothly rather than abruptly transitioning from second to second.  Without the `Behavior` line in the code below, I get a stepped-second but otherwise correct behavior.  With the `Behavior` line, it works perfectly until the seconds go from 59 back to 0, and then it goes *counter clockwise* which is not all the behavior I want.

I read that using `SmoothedAnimation` would help, but when I tried substituting `SmoothedAnimation` for `NumberAnimation` it does a stepped-second until the 59 to 0 transition and then goes counter clockwise.

How do I alter this to have it **only** rotate clockwise but do so smoothly?

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 320; height: 320
    Item {
        property var time: new Date()
        id: wallClock
        Timer {
            interval: 1000
            running: true
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: wallClock.time = new Date()
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        x: parent.width/2
        y: parent.height/2 - 100
        width: 10; height: 70
        color: "red"
        transform: Rotation {
            origin.x: rect1.width/2
            origin.y: rect1.height
            angle: wallClock.time.getSeconds()*6
            Behavior on angle { NumberAnimation { duration: 1000 } }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a `NumberAnimation` or `SmoothedAnimation`, I think a `RotationAnimation` is what you want. The advantage there is that it allows you to force the direction to remain clockwise.

```
        transform: Rotation {
            origin.x: rect1.width/2
            origin.y: rect1.height
            angle: wallClock.time.getSeconds()*6
            Behavior on angle { RotationAnimation { duration: 1000; direction: RotationAnimation.Clockwise} }
        }
```